# 0A prepended to BLOBs upon retrieval using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, binary, blob

For better or worse, I am storing binary information in a database table and am having a problem retrieving it.  Each BLOB has a newline prepended to it upon retrieval, at least, I believe it's upon retrieval, as the binary object in the table is exactly the same size as the source file.

I've searched for a similar problem to mine, and the closest I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860086/mysql-blob-field-has-first-line-of-space-and-therefore-wont-play-file)  However, I am using PDO instead of mysql_* and I have checked for empty lines prior to the opening

Here's the retrieval function stored in a separate file that I'm including in my test:

(in raw.php):

```
function return_raw_rawid($raw_id)  {
    $data = array();
    $aggregate_data = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `raw` WHERE `raw_id` = :rawid";

    try {
        $db_obj = dbCore::getInstance();
        $query = $db_obj->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue(':rawid', $raw_id);

        if ($query->execute()) {
            while($results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))   {
                $data['raw_id']     = $results['raw_id'];
                $data['filename']   = $results['filename'];
                $data['mime_type']  = $results['mime_type'];
                $data['file_size']  = $results['file_size'];
                $data['file_data']  = $results['file_data'];
                $data['test_id']    = $results['test_id'];
                $data['user_id']    = $results['user_id'];
                $data['time']       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $results['time']);
                $aggregate_data[]   = $data;
            } // while
        }  // if
        $query->closeCursor();

        return $aggregate_data;

    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $errors[] = $ex;
    } // catch
}
```

Here's the code I'm testing it with in a separate file:

```
<?php 
include 'core/init.php'; // Contains protect_page() and includes for return_raw_rawid
protect_page();
$blob_id = 20;
$blob = return_raw_rawid($blob_id);
$data = ltrim($blob[0]['file_data']);
$name = ltrim($blob[0]['filename']);
$size = ltrim($blob[0]['file_size']);
$type = ltrim($blob[0]['mime_type']);
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
echo $data;
```

When I load this page in my browser, it will prompt me to download the file identified by blob_id and has the correct filename and type.  However, upon downloading it and opening in ghex, I see that the first byte is '0A'  Using

```
cmp original_file downloaded_file
```

I determine that the only difference is this first byte.  Googling led me to the ltrim() function that I've (perhaps too) liberally applied above.

I can't tell for sure if this problem is not being caused during upload, though as I said before, I don't believe it is since the "file_size" value in phpmyadmin is exactly the same as the source file.  I'm not sure if the use of the aggregate_data array in the retrieval function could be to blame or what.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure those 4 header lines are being properly executed? 0x0A is the newline char. You could have a newline in your core/init.php triggering output, and the headers are never executed. With display_errors/error_reporting off, you'd never see the warnings about "headers not sent - output started at line X...".

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It must be something I'm including from my init.php.  I took out all functions that I separated out into other files and put everything I needed in one place.  I think what I need to do is re-evaluate how I'm going about retrieving this data from MySQL.
Now to determine what else could be triggering the output...

Comment: storing files in a db is useful in certain limited cases, but as a general storage system it's a cause of far more problems than the minor usefulness could ever compensate for.

Comment: For this project, my requirements dictate that I store data in BLOBs.  I discovered the solution for my issue was to clear the output buffer as, indeed, you were right in that something I included off of init was triggering output.  By adding "ob_clean();" immediately after the includes, I solved my problem.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!